# How to store numbers of a file in a array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, file, integer, readfile

I need to read a file with numbers and then store this numbers in a array, after that I need to remove the repeated numbers presenting in the array and subscribe the file. The problem is I can't even put the numbers on the file in a array of integers, I debbugged the code and the file is really opened, but the while don't work to store the numbers in the array.

The code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    int radica[50];
    int i=0;

    // open file
    FILE *myFile = fopen("input.txt","r");//for ideone//fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // if opening file fails, print error message and exit 1
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error: Failed to open file.");
        return 1;
    }
    rewind(myFile);

    do{
        fscanf(myFile,"%1d",&radica[i]); //Storing the number into the array
        i++;
    }while(feof(myFile));

    // close file
    fclose(myFile);
    //printing the numbers
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d\n", radica[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the file contains: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 5 8 8 6 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 8 8

Comment: What are the return values (not the read values in "radica") of fsanf() and what do they mean according to fscanf dokumentation?

Comment: `fscanf` returns a value to let you know if it worked, and your `getc` is eating characters from the file.

Comment: @Aidan but the format inside the fscanf it's "%1d"

Comment: BTW `fclose` is duplicated. Also `"EOF"` --> `EOF`, `j<50;` --> `j < i;`

Comment: I removed the quotes EOF, sorry. But it still not workin

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I didnt see it was duplicated, btw, I changed all this things but still not working

Comment: see [DEMO](https://ideone.com/MM2RUh)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I copied and pasted your Demo, but still..

Comment: If you can not read _"still not working"_ you say, I think that the format of the file is different from what you expect.

Comment: Its just a txt, And the file has been read in the main, the problem is in the while, It dont store into the array

Comment: When I debbugged the line  "fscanf(myFile,"%1d",&radica[i]);", it's showing "connected" and aborting the executation

Comment: The reason why the file can not be read is, for example, that a character other than a numerical value exists at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I thought this, but the file is full of number, and the order is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 5 8 8 6 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 8 8

Comment: Even if some problems remain, the code shown in the demo will work. Your situation can not be reproduced.

Comment: I know, Now his not opening the file correctly, but its no reading nothing, and I is only increased once

Comment: Try Put `while((c = getc(myFile))!=EOF)
  putchar(c);
 putchar('\n');
 rewind(myFile);` before do-while. Will the contents of the file be displayed?

Comment: `while(feof(myFile));` means 'while end of file reached'... How about `while(!feof(myFile));`. But remember that will mean the last read failed.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, the contents were displayed, and now the Array is stored. thank YOU

Comment: _I copied and pasted your Demo_ You need change `FILE *myFile = stdin;//for ideone//fopen("input.txt", "r");` to `FILE *myFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");`

Answer (score 0):

Now its working, Thank you guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    int radica[50];
    int i=0;

    // open file
    FILE *myFile = fopen("input.txt","r");//for ideone//fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // if opening file fails, print error message and exit 1
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error: Failed to open file.");
        return 1;
    }

    do{
        fscanf(myFile,"%1d",&radica[i]); //Storing the number into the array
        i++;
    }while(c=getc(myFile)!=EOF);

    // close file
    fclose(myFile);
    //printing the numbers
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%d\n", radica[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```